# print each word in separate lines

Tags: c

My program aims to print each word in the sentence on a separate line.but I should print it with **%s not %c**! I already try to implement it but the program does not give me a correct output ! my idea is when you find null character 
1- print the word
 2- return the index of the temp array to 0 and store a new word

```
 int main () {
    char sen[100];
    char cpy [100];
    printf("Entter a sentence "); 
    gets(sen);
    int len = strlen(sen);
    int i = 0; 
    int k =0;
    for (i=0 ; i<len;i++) 
    {
       if (sen[i]!='\0')
       {
          cpy[k++]+=sen[i];
       }
       else{
          printf("%s\n",cpy);
          k=0;}
    }

 }
```

Comment: Use `fgets` - not `gets` - buffer overruns see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: i don't read from file i read it from the user

Comment: `sen[i]!='\0'`  does not become false in for-loop. Word separator is not only _null character_, white-space character punctuation etc.

Comment: @JavaisFun Then use `fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin)`. `stdin` means "read from the input stream", which is user input, unless it is re-directed on start-up.

Comment: yeah i already include #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

Comment: `sen[i]!='\0'` - This is always going to be true

Answer (score 2):

You confound null character and space character. Null character `\0` stands for "end of string" : the strlen function returns the number of characters before the first `\0`.

In your forloop, you want to display each word separated by  so you have to test with the caracter  instead of `\0`.

Also to correctly display your string you have to end the string with the `\0` character. So before the instruction `printf` you must do `cpy[k] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 0):

`if (sen[i]!='\0')` will always be true as pointed by Julien Vernay, you need `if (sen[i]!= ' ')` instead of `if (sen[i]!='\0')`, as there are spaces between words, to seprate them.

Also in `cpy[k++]+=sen[i];` you are adding `sen[i]` to `cpy[k++]` which seams weird, I think what you need is `cpy[k++] = sen[i];`

Modify your loop as follows...

```
for (i=0 ; i<len; i++) {
   int flag = 0;
   while(sen[i] == ' ') i++; // multiple spaces

   while(sen[i] != ' ' && sen[i] != '\0') {
      cpy[k++] = sen[i];
      flag = 1;
      i++;
   }
   if(flag) {
     cpy[k] = '\0';
     printf("%s\n",cpy);
     k=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you mention some cases??

Comment: its fixed now !!

Comment: yup, I thought it would be `if(k) printf("%s\n",cpy);`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yeah, but that would strict only printing... while we need not construct word at all for spaces!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have to not bother with doing a copy - all you need to do is essentially replace spaces with new lines. So here is the code to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char sen[100];
   bool last_char_space = true;
   printf("Please enter a sentence: ");
   fflush(stdout);
   fgets(sen, 100, stdin);;
   for (int loop = 0; sen[loop]; ++loop) { // send[loop] is true until end of string - saves repeatedly calling strlen
     if (send[loop] == ' ') { // A space
       if (last_char_space) { // Last character not a space, put new line
         fputc('\n', stdout);
       }
       last_char_space = true; // Record the fact that we are between words
     } else {
       fputc(sen[loop], stdout); // Not a space - print it
       last_char_space = false;  // We are working on a word
     }
   }
   return 0;
}
```